# Timer that can be paused in a text game

Tags: java, android, timer

I need a timer that can be paused in a text game. Currently using a CountDowntimer. Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: your timer should run continuously, but use a boolean control flag to define if  the variable must be increased...

Answer (score 0):

#### A - Explanation

A timer simply needs a start/stop mechanism and a storage for the duration value. Additionally, we need a boolean flag (`isCounting`) to track the state of the timer.

I've written a simple demo code down below;

#### B - Timer Class Code

```
package com.levent.timer;

public class Timer {

    private long timer;
    private long temp;
    private boolean isCounting;

    public Timer() {
        this.timer = 0;
        this.temp = 0;
        this.isCounting = false;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        if(!isCounting) {
            isCounting = true;

            this.temp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    public void holdTimer() {
        if(isCounting) {
            isCounting = false;
            long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - this.temp;

            this.timer += delta;
            this.temp = 0;
        }
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return this.timer;
    }

    public void clearTimer() {
        this.timer = 0;
        this.temp = 0;
        this.isCounting = false;
    }
}
```

#### C - Timer Demo Code

```
package com.levent.timer;

public class TimerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.startTimer();
        System.out.println("Timer Started");
        System.out.println("*************");
        System.out.println("timer initial value: " + timer.getDuration());

        /*
         * Wait timer for 1 sec, time will count this duration
         */
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        timer.holdTimer();
        System.out.println("timer value at T1  : " + timer.getDuration());

        /*
         * Wait timer for 2 sec, timer will NOT count on this duration
         * timer duration value won't change
         */
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println("timer value at T2  : " + timer.getDuration());

        timer.startTimer();
        /*
         * Wait timer for 2 sec
         * Timer will count on this duration,
         * Expected timer duration value is ~3000 ms
         */
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        timer.holdTimer();
        System.out.println("timer value at T3  : " + timer.getDuration());
    }

}
```

#### D - Sample Output

```
Timer Started
*************
timer initial value: 0
timer value at T1  : 1000
timer value at T2  : 1000
timer value at T3  : 3001
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean variable to control the timer

```
public class SceneToScene extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean continueTimer = true;
```

to start the timer

```
    Timer();
```

make the method Timer()

```
private void Timer() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 1000ms

            if (continueTimer) Timer();

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

to stop the timer,

```
continueTimer = false;
```

timer will repeats in every 1000ms (1sec)

to restart,

```
continueTimer = true;
Timer();
```